# Visual Studio 2015 branch and merge issue with .vs folder

Tags: tfs, merge, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to do a merge from one branch to another inside a TFS team project.
Neither of the branches includes the .vs folder at the root level, so why does it show up in the list of changes for the merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“.vs” folder at the root of the solution contains project related files. This is a new feature in VS 2015.

Check links below, which will give you more inforamtion:

- https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6079923-store-project-related-information-in-vs-folder-to?page=1&per_page=20
- https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/i-asked-for-a-vs-folder-and-the-vs-team-gave-it-to-me/

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, but it looks like something wonky was going on with my solution. It seems that my specific issue was an anomaly, because I couldn't reproduce it.
The .vs folder is always going to be a part of a solution, but it should be a silent /ignored part. VS should ignore it when merging files from one branch to another. In my special case, it didn't.